# Loki-stack Helm Chart Storage and Retention with GCS

Tags: grafana-loki, google-cloud-storage

I'm running a local kubernetes cluster (minikube) and I have grafana installed in a namespace and the [loki-stack](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/loki-stack) helm chart installed in another namespace. I can query logs on my grafana instance and everything works out of the box. (I'm using the promtail version that comes with the loki-stack chart as my logging agent).

I have some questions about how to configure storage and retention of logs using the loki-stack chart. There seems to be a lack of proper official documentation for configuring yamls for this chart.

**My goal is to store logs in GCS, and configure the retention period.** I was wondering if I could get access to a complete yaml for doing so as I'm unable to figure out how to use the [yaml section that's outlined in the official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/retention/). I also know that storing in GCS involves obtaining a credentials file and linking it with the loki instance, but I'm unsure of how to do that in the yaml for the loki-stack chart. I would appreciate any help with this matter.

Fyi, my current yaml is pasted below. It's just the default loki-stack yaml without the disabled features.

```
loki:
  enabled: true

promtail:
  enabled: true
```